# How to send ACK message to client from server using NetMQ

Tags: c#, zeromq, netmq

I am using NetMQ to send messages from many clients to a server which receives the messages and processes them. If I use the ***pub/sub*** pattern, I can (ab)use the subscriber socket and use it for the server and clients will be the publishers (the opposite flow, isn't it?). However, I cannot send an acknowledge message to the clients.

If I use the `REQ/RESP` pattern, I can use the response socket for the server and even send an acknowledge message which can be received by the client. However, if the server misses the message from client, I cannot resend the message (after waiting for a `timespan`), because I receive an exception

> Req.XSend - cannot send another request

-- even after disconnecting the client socket and closing it (it seams that the server socket keeps track of it).

And finally, based on the documentation, I'm not sure if the `Dealer/Router` is the right pattern to use. As I'm pretty sure that I'm stuck in a very common situation, is there any pattern to implement this scenario using NetMQ?

Comment: Just a suggestion, the bold/italics are a bit obnoxious.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I just did it to make it easier to read, if you think it's not a good idea I appreciate any edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are stuck in a very common problem, typically called "Reliable Request-Reply" in 0MQ parlance.

There are several approaches described in the [guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Client-Side-Reliability-Lazy-Pirate-Pattern), the first is the "lazy pirate". In it you use a REQ/RESP socket pair as described (though REQ/ROUTER would work just as well, and probably better for more than one client). The solution is to dispose of the socket if your ACK times out and create a new one.

The guide does note that swapping a DEALER for the REQ would solve the problem, but adds having to keep track of the envelope yourself. Unless you need async send/receive on the client side for some other reason, I would follow their advice and stick with REQ/ROUTER.

A sample implementation of this pattern can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/NetMQ/Samples/tree/master/src/Pirate%20Pattern

Comment: As the question explicitly mentions NetMQ, maybe you can use this https://github.com/NetMQ/Samples/tree/master/src/Pirate%20Pattern reference, which points to the implementation presented by Doron Somech, to make the answer even more useful to the future viewers.

Comment: @mok Thanks for linking that for me, I added it to the answer.